# A school has 5 distinct classes and 15 students. In how many ways can the students be arranged if each class has to have at least two students?

Tags: combinatorics

My take:

First, we assign two students to each class, this can be done in $${15\choose 2}\times {13\choose 2}\times{11\choose 2}\times{9\choose 2}\times{7\choose 2}  = \frac{15!}{(2!)^55!}$$ ways. We're left with $5$ students to arrange. Each one of them can be assigned to $5$ different classes, hence there are $5^5$ possible ways to distribute the students among the classes. The final result is thus $$\left( \frac{5}{2} \right)^5\times \frac{15!}{5!}$$

Do you see anything wrong with this?

Comment: Are the students supposed to be distinguishable or identical?

Comment: I don’t see anything wrong, considering the students are distinct.

Comment: @doobdood distinguishable

Comment: My opinion: First, you assigned two students to each class so it is division of $10$ students in $5$ classes. I mean, the formula is $\displaystyle \frac{(mn)!}{(n!)^mm!}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do see something wrong with it. Your logic incorrectly distinguishes between a student as having been selected as a part of the initial two sudents for a class versus being a part of the excess students assigned to a class. Your count that you found was instead the answer to the related but different problem of "You have 15 distinct students assigned to 5 distinct classes such that in each class you have exactly two students designated as teacher's pets"

Annoyingly, the number of times that you have overcounted each scenario varies based on the exact number of students in each class. The arrangements where there are three students in each class you overcounted in $3^5$ ways (by picking which of the students wasn't the teacher's pet) meanwhile the arrangement where all excess students went to the first class was instead overcounted in $\binom{7}{2}$ ways. So, "division by symmetry" is not going to be the way to go here to correct the count.

As for a corrected approach... I don't see an especially clean one, but you should be able to manage with inclusion-exclusion and case-work... considering the events $A_0,A_1,B_0,B_1,C_0,\dots$ corresponding to class A having exactly zero students, class A having exactly one student, class B having zero students, etc... This will admittedly be a bit tedious

> $5^{15}-5\cdot 4^{15}-5\cdot 15\cdot 4^{14} + \binom{5}{2}\cdot 3^{15}+5\cdot 4\cdot 15\cdot 3^{14} + \binom{5}{2}\cdot 15\cdot 14\cdot 3^{13} - \dots$

Alternatively, one *could* approach directly by cases.  This is almost never encouraged and I really hope someone comes up with a better suggestion, but the problem is just small enough that I would still consider it feasible and might be of similar tedium as the inclusion-exclusion approach above in the end.

So, consider the compositions of $15$ into five parts of increasing size where each part is of size at least $2$ and find the count of ways in which classes can be arranged into partitions of this type and arrangements of students into those class sizes.

2-2-2-2-7: $\binom{5}{1}\dfrac{15!}{(2!)^47!}$

2-2-2-3-6: $\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\dfrac{15!}{(2!)^33!6!}$

2-2-2-4-5: $\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\dfrac{15!}{(2!)^34!5!}$

$\vdots$

2-2-3-4-4: $\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\dfrac{15!}{(2!)^23!(4!)^2}$

$\vdots$

Comment: Ah, I see now. I was led astray by the fact that this method works when the objects are indistinguishable. Thank you for the input.